# Order of variable assignment evaluation in SELECT can differ from order of rows returned. Under what conditions can this occur?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I was recently trying to use a user-defined variable to capture some information from the *last* row returned in my result set.

What I mean is, for example if I have a list of names from 'Aaron' to 'Zzarx',

```
SELECT @n:=Name FROM people ORDER BY Name;
SELECT @n;
```

The second `SELECT` should return 'Zzarx'.

That's the simple case.  It works as expected; variable assignment reliably occurs in the same order as rows are sent to the client, so the last assignment corresponds to the last returned row.

But strange things seem to happen when the query is more complicated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(@n:=Name,'unknown') FROM people ORDER BY <some non-indexed expression> LIMIT 10;
SELECT @n;
```

Executing something like this on MariaDB v10.3.16 I get a final value of @n (from the second `SELECT`) **that doesn't correspond to any of the rows returned by the first `SELECT`!**.  (Note that Name is a `NOT NULL` column, so the `IFNULL()` is actually redundant, but is still necessary to trigger this behaviour).

Note that it only seems to happen when ALL of the following hold:

- `SELECT DISTINCT`
- `ORDER BY` can't use an index
- The variable assignment happens inside some expression

My *theory* is that:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` forces early evaluation of the returned column expressions.
- `ORDER BY (non-indexed expression)` forces an explicit sort operation after column data has been evaluated.
- The SQL engine is smart enough to recognize the simple `SELECT @var := (expression)` pattern and evaluate @var only as the row is sent to the client, but can't make that optimization if the `@var:=...` assignment is embedded inside a larger expression, as in the `IFNULL()` in my example.

However, this is all only guesswork.
The manual page on user-defined variables doesn't really say anything useful in this regard (neither MySQL's nor MariaDB's).

It seems to me that using a @variable to capture something from the last-returned row in a multi-row query is a useful and probably quite commonplace trick, but now I'm not sure whether or when I can rely on it.  Similarly for lots of row-numbering and other clever schemes I've seen that utilize @variables in the result set part of a `SELECT`.

Does someone here on SO have any definitive information on how this is supposed to work, and specifically, *under what conditions will the order of evaluations of row variable-assignment expressions be guaranteed to correspond to the actual order of rows returned?*

***...Because this seems to be quite an important thing to know!***

---

Another, slightly less pathological example:

Say table t has 1000 rows:

```
SET @n:=0;
SELECT @n:=@n+1 FROM t ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 5;
SELECT @n;
```

Returned result sets are:

```
1000
 999
 998
 997
 996
```

and

```
1000
```

Note that once again, the final value of `@n` does NOT correspond to the last row returned, and indeed given the semantics of the query, in this case it can't.

Comment: ...And because I just know someone is going to call me on it:  "Whaddya mean Zzarx isn't a name? I hazz a vezzy good fziend named Zzarx!!!"

Answer (score 4):

Although you are not using 8.0.13, the following will be coming soon.  You have found a reason why it is coming.

> ----- 2018-10-22 8.0.13 General Availability -- -- Important Change -----
>
> Setting user variables in statements other than
>   [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) is
>   now deprecated due to issues that included those listed here:
>
> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables was
>   undefined.
>
> The default result type of a variable is based on its type at the
>   beginning of the statement, which could have unintended effects when a
>   variable holding a value of one type at the beginning of a statement
>   was assigned a new value of a different type in the same statement.
>
> HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY clauses, when referring to a variable
>   that was assigned a value in the select expression list, did not work
>   as expected because the expression was evaluated on the client and so
>   it was possible for stale column values from a previous row to be
>   used.
>
> Syntax such as SELECT @var, @var:=@var+1 is still accepted in MySQL
>   8.0 for backward compatibility, but is subject to removal in a future release.

-- From the "change log".

Think of `DISTINCT` as similar to `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT @v := ... FROM t ORDER BY x;
```

Case 1:  `INDEX(x)` but the Optimizer may choose to fetch the rows, then sort them.

Case 2:  `INDEX(x)` and the Optimizer chooses to fetch the rows based on the index.

```
SELECT @v := ... FROM t  GROUP BY w  ORDER BY x;
```

This almost certainly requires generating a temp table (for ordering), maybe two (one for grouping and one for ordering).  The only rational way to run the query is to evaluate the expressions (including @v) in the `SELECT`, gather the results, then proceed to grouping and ordering.  So, the evaluation order is not likely to be that of `x`.  But it *might* mimic `w`.

What about `PARTITIONing`?  Currently, there is no parallelism in MySQL's evaluation of a `SELECT`.  But, what if that came into existence?  Let's take an 'obvious' case -- separate threads working on separate `PARTITIONs` of the table.  All bets are off in the order of evaluation.

Once that' is implemented, the how about splitting up even a non-partitioned `SELECT` to get some parallelism?

You are not going to win the argument.

Yes, it may stay "deprecated" for a long time.  Or maybe there will be a `sql_mode` that runs queries the "old" way.  Or the existence of @variables inhibits certain optimizations (in favor of predictability).  Etc.

May I suggest that you write a "feature request" at bugs.mysql.com , stating what you would like to see.  (You could also do it at mariadb.com, but they look at the former.)

Comment: Yeah, I had actually already read something to that effect on the MySQL v8 manual's "User Variables" page.  So it's deprecated in MySQL (not AFAIK in MariaDB, at least not yet).  But I don't for a second believe they'll ever actually remove it; it would break backward-compatibility much too badly.  Deprecated or not, I'd still like to know when I can rely on (evaluation order)=(row order).

Comment: Also I don't think the `GROUP BY` thing is quite the same... that's more about the `GROUP BY` using a value different to the final value returned in the `SELECT`.  Whereas my question is about order of evaluation vs order of  returned rows, which I think is a different issue.

Comment: Also, they mention that `SELECT @var, @var:=@var+1` might be removed... but that contains a whole different problem:  *Column* evaluation order is not determinate, which is the main reason you should never do that.

Comment: @Doin - I rambled on some more in my Answer.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  I think you answered my question.  I don't really have a feature request here, I just wanted some clarity about when it was/wasn't safe to assume an evaluation order - and you've answered that very clearly!

Comment: r.e. Deprecation, quite aside from a lot of legacy code that does things like e.g. `SELECT value, @runningtotal:=@runningtotal+value FROM table...` there's definitely still a use case for `SELECT @a:=a, @b:=b,... FROM table WHERE UniqueID=...`, i.e. return a single row, but also simultaneously capture some of the column values for use in later SQL computations in the same session.  That's entirely unambiguous, and while there are other ways to do it (e.g. with a temp table, or merely repeating the query), they're quite cumbersome and inefficient if you only want a few scalars.

Comment: @Doin - The functionality will remain; the syntax will change:  MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB have both "windowing" functions and CTEs.  This will probably provide "running totals" (and many other features) in a 'standard', predictable way.  The syntax changes are very significant, so I hope it will "stay deprecated for a long time.

Comment: Yes, I was actually looking trough the new windowing function syntax for MariaDB just a couple of days ago. It could certainly do the running total thing (though given its generality, I wonder if it would be as efficient?).  My point was, though, that there's a lot of legacy code out there using variables in the "deprecated" way; and while window functions might cover much of the same territory conceptually, it'd involve a lot more than minor syntactic changes to upgrade them.

Comment: Also, what about the case of sending a (single) row to the client, while simultaneously saving some of its column values for later use on the SQL side?  That's a good reason not to completely remove the `SELECT @var:=colvalue` syntax, IMHO.

Comment: @Doin - You have several compelling arguments for your feature request.

Comment: Rick, you win!  I went and submitted a (sort-of) feature request to MySQL (if you consider "please don't remove *XYZ* without providing an alternative" as a "feature request").  You can view it here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96163.  I included lots of stuff not discussed above as well.

Comment: Rick, I just reread your bit about `GROUP BY w  ORDER BY x;` and I suspect you're not 100% right.  Temporary structures created for ordering wouldn't include all the returned column data, they'd just include a key and the expressions being ordered on; a temp index rather than a temo table in other words (GROUP BY is different, since it computes aggregates of all returned columns, and need places to put them... Note ANY_VALUE() is implicit on any result columns without an explicit aggregte).

Comment: ...also when a column expression *begins* with `@var:=` the optimizer (it would seem) strips that away for the purposes of GROUP BY/ORDER BY/DISTINCT, and adds it back at the time the rows get sent to the client.  That's why in my original question I had to use `SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(@n:=Name,'unknown')` instead of just `SELECT DISTINCT @n:=Name` - even though `Name` was a NOT NULL column, so they should be functionally identical.

Comment: @Doin - I _believe_ that the evaluator will gather all the needed columns (and no extras) and carry them through the `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`.  Note that those may involve expressions that would (I assume) be evaluated early, then hung onto until needed (as in `ORDER BY`).

Comment: @Doin - I preceive `ANY_VALUE` as a reminder to the programmer that the value is unpredictable, and a clue to the Optimizer that it can do whatever is most efficient.

Comment: Rick, thanks for the bug report upvote!  Also yes, the evaluator will gather all *needed* columns.  But that doesn't include everything to be sent to the client, because that's done at the last step.  What I mean is that if you have an Employees table with EmployeeID (primary key), Name, Salary, and JobCategory, and you `SELECT Name,... ORDER BY JobCategory, Salary`, then no temporary structure would include Name, because it's not used until the row is actually sent.  Instead, the temporary structures would just link to the original table row, via primary key or maybe a pointer of some kind.

Comment: ANY_VALUE doesn't affect the optimizer, because it's either *always* implied in an aggregating context whether you use it or not, or else not using it gives you an error (depending on the server mode settings).  It does flag to the programmer the use of a non-aggregate expression in an aggregate context, and what that will mean!

Comment: What I was trying to say was that I thought that when aggregating, temporary structures would have to treat non-aggregate expressions differently to the way they normally would.  But on further reflection, that's not so:  Anything not being grouped or ordered on or aggregated, can be calculated as it's sent, and only a row pointer needs to be kept for it until then.

Comment: @Doin - Unlike other RDBMS brands, InnoDB does not really have "row pointers".  Instead, it uses the value of the `PRIMARY KEY` for the row to uniquely identify a row and be able to fetch it.  However, I can't think of a case where it would hang onto the PK instead of hanging onto the row.  (There may be some internal actions, like sorting, that do something like shuffling pointers instead of row text.)

Comment: So, you're saying that if I issue a SELECT with 99 columns (expressions), ordered by a 100th, the optimizer is going to create a temporary structure with rows of *100 columns*, fill them *all* in, and then sort based on one of them?  Prior to a LIMIT clause possibly deleting most of them?  That would be very... non-optimal!

Comment: @Doin - True.  The alternative is to hang onto an arbitrarily large number of rows each with an arbitrarily large amount of data.  This would imply multiple techniques for trying to do it in RAM, then spilling to disk, etc.  MySQL started out will a reasonably broad list of features, each implemented with minimal effort.  Over the years, new optimizations have been added.  Your 'pointer' suggestion is probably far down the list.

Comment: Umm.  So if there are 100,000 rows in my table and I say "ORDER BY <expression> LIMIT 10", MySQL is going to separately evaluate and store (100 x 100,000 = 10,000,000) expressions, (99 x 99,990 = 9,899,010) of which will be discarded without ever being used for anything?  Sorry, I think you're wrong.  Also, without *some* form of (internal) row pointers other than PKs, it would not be possible to create an index on any table that didn't have a primary key.  (And it is possible, obviously).

Comment: @Doin - And that is an optimization that I sometimes recommend.  (A derived table fetching only `id`, and having `LIMIT 10`, then `JOIN` back to the table to set the 100x10 cells needed for the resultset.)

Comment: Ok, wow.  I was sure you were always 100% wrong, but it seems that *IFF* the ORDER BY expression is nondeterministic and needs to be stored, MySQL precalculates it along with the WHOLE result row.  (Normally, though, it doesn't do this, you should note: normally ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... will only calculate row data for the rows actually sent).  Proof here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQehPzWyhFbvc4bhuiAP2x/1

Comment: @Doin - _If_ a single index can handle all the `WHERE` _and_ the `ORDER BY`, then the evaluation can stop after `LIMIT` rows.

Comment: It has nothing to do with indexes. See the example I linked to:  There are NO indexes there (nor even a primary key).